# xampp,php-java-bridge show notice: Undefined property: java_Client::$cancelProxyCreationTag

Tags: java, php, xampp, php-java-bridge

i get the following notice when I try to use javaBridge because I want to use java code in php,I followed some tutorials but encoutered following things

```
Undefined property: java_Client::$cancelProxyCreationTag in D:\xampp\htdocs\java\Java.inc on line 1994
```

the whole test.php file is as follows, except the notice the other things is normal,

```
php-java-bridge config...

Java version=1.7.0_55 

Notice: Undefined property: java_Client::$cancelProxyCreationTag in D:\xampp\htdocs\java\Java.inc on line 1994
Java vendor=Oracle Corporation 
OS=Windows 7 6.1 on amd64 
星期三, 八月 27, 2014 at 4:56:58 下午 中国标准时间
```

Does anybody have encounter the same trouble? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's simple just add the attribute `$cancelProxyCreationTag` in the `java_Client` class

```
//Java.inc
class java_Client {
...
public $cancelProxyCreationTag;
...
}
```

This attribute is used in the Java destruct method . its mandatory if you are using the bridge in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this from the PHP code that's using the bridge in case you don't want to crack open the war/jar files and redeploy.

```
//...
$workbook = new Java('org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook');
$workbook->__client->cancelProxyCreationTag = 0;
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Solving this problem requires fixing two interrelated issues.

First, there is no `java/Java.inc` file deployed in the original [JavaBridge.war](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/download.php). It is generated, which is problematic due to the bug, which you've encountered, that lurks inside `java/Java.inc`.

Second, the `java/Java.inc` file contains a variable that is incremented before it is initialized.

Fix these issues as follows:

1. Download the [JavaBridge.war](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Binary%20package/php-java-bridge_6.2.1/php-java-bridge_6.2.1_documentation.zip/download) file.
2. Extract the `java/Java.inc` file by calling: `java -cp JavaBridge.war TestInstallation`, as per the [documentation](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/installation.php).
3. Fix any errors that appear (such as a missing php5-cli).
4. Edit `java/Java.inc`.
5. Go to line 1994.
6. Insert the following code immediately above line 1994:

```
    if( empty($client->cancelProxyCreationTag) ) {
      $client->cancelProxyCreationTag = 0;
    }
```

The `else` block (lines 1989 to 1998) should resemble:

```
} else {
$result=clone($client->cachedJavaPrototype);
$result->__factory=$cacheEntry->factory;
$result->__java=++$client->asyncCtx;
$result->__signature=$cacheEntry->signature;
// FIX: initialize variable before it is used.
if( empty($client->cancelProxyCreationTag) ) { 
  $client->cancelProxyCreationTag = 0;
} 
$result->__cancelProxyCreationTag=++$client->cancelProxyCreationTag;
return $result;
```

Save the file.

Next, re-create the .war file as follows:

1. Create a new, empty, temporary directory
2. Unzip the original JavaBridge war file into the temporary directory.
3. Move the `java` directory into the temporary directory; be sure that it includes the updated `Java.inc` file!
4. Archive the broken `JavaBridge.war` file.
5. Create a new version of the JavaBridge.

For example, this might resemble:

```
mkdir temp
unzip ../JavaBridge.war
mv ../java .
mv ../JavaBridge.war /tmp
zip -r ../JavaBridge.war *
```

The problem should be resolved.